# Monitor file acess of a running application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Is it possible to monitor programatically file access of some running app on OSX? Creating/releasing file handle/descriptor? I need to know when some app reads from file and stops reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not personally done what you're asking, but here are a few pointers that might get you started.

Mac OS X comes with a command-line program, [fs_usage](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fs_usage.1.html), that does that, and more.  You might be able to launch it as a helper app and parse its output.

```
$ sudo fs_usage -f filesys Safari
22:43:27  stat64            ry/Safari/Bookmarks.plist    0.000063   Safari      
22:43:28  lstat64           English.lproj/Browser.nib    0.000025   Safari      
22:43:28  getattrlist       English.lproj/Browser.nib    0.000014   Safari      
22:43:28  getattrlist       English.lproj/Browser.nib    0.000017   Safari      
22:43:28  open              English.lproj/Browser.nib    0.000017   Safari      
22:43:28  getdirentriesattr                              0.000039   Safari      
22:43:28  close                                          0.000008   Safari
```

opensnoop does a similar thing.

```
$ sudo opensnoop
  UID    PID COMM          FD PATH                 
  205    284 locationd     -1 /dev/dlci.spi-baseband.9 
  501   2836 Safari        11 /Users/zach/Library/Cookies/Cookies.plist
```

opensnoop is built on [dtrace](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtrace.1.html), which could almost certainly do what you want.  There's a decent tutorial on it [here](http://preserve.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.23/23.11/ExploringLeopardwithDTrace/index.html).

Finally, if you don't mind using private API, there's one which was built for Spotlight, which provides a notification system for filesystem changes.  [This tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20200502165655/http://osxbook.com/software/fslogger/) is built on it.  The source code is available.

Comment: I found dtrace few minutes after I posted question. I dont like idea that user will have to elevate privileges for the app, but I think it is the only way.